# Spring Data MongoDB auto create indexes not working

Tags: spring, spring-data

I am using Spring data Mongodb v1.6.2 and Spring 4.2.1. Today I noticed that @Indexed annotation on my entities did not trigger an index creation.

The entity is annotated with org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document and theorg.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document is used.

```
@Document
public class Entity {
 @Indexed(unique= true)
 private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation it appeared that MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator did not receive the MappingContextEvent. Spring 4.2 altered the way generics are handled for ApplicationEvents.

Spring Data MongoDB fixed this in the following commit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/2a27eb74044d6480b228a216c1f93b2b0488c59a
The issue tracker can be found here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1224
This was fixed in all version so upgrading to 1.6.3 fixed the issue.